# SQL order by clause for 2 date columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a column named `timestamp`

i want to be able to order by month(*timestamp*) and year(*timestamp*) and group the months and years together

so for example, if i had the following timestamps:

```
2014-01-01
2014-02-01
2014-05-01
2015-01-01
```

i want to show in this order

```
MONTH    YEAR
1        2015
5        2014
2        2014
1        2014
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pick *month* and *year* from *timestamp* with `MONTH` and `YEAR`:

```
GROUP BY MONTH(field_with_ts) , YEAR(field_with_ts)
```

and the same thing with the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
substring(date, 8 , 2) as Month, substring(date, 1, 3) as Year
```

See, if that works.